# Angle between plane and line

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry, angle

I'm getting a really large angle when I work out this problem and I'm not sure why. I have a plane which has the equation: $0.19x-0.68y+0.7x = -2.19$. I took a point which is on the plane and called it $Q$ (in this example it's the center of the hexagon) along with the point  S to compute vector $\mathbf Q \mathbf S$. In the schematic,  $r$ would just be the magnitude of $\mathbf Q \mathbf S$ and in order to find $\theta$ I would use the following equation:
$cos \theta =\left(\frac{\mathbf n \cdot \mathbf Q\mathbf S}{\mathbf {\vert \mathbf n \vert} \cdot {\mathbf {\vert Q \mathbf S \vert}}} \right) $ where $ \mathbf n $ is $<0.19, -0.68,  0.7>$.  Am I approaching this correctly?

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is the correct equation for $\cos\theta$, so looks good. Seems like you've done some work and gotten an unexpected answer... Add the question you're actually trying to answer, your work, the answer your got, and perhaps why you think it was unexpected.

Comment: Depending on the position of point $S$, the angle $\theta$ can be more than $90^{\circ}$ What value did you get?

Comment: As Vasya indicates, $\theta$ can be anywhere from $0$ to $\pi \equiv 180^\circ$. if $\bf n$ is pointing to the opposite side of the plane from where $S$ is, the angle will be greater than $\frac \pi 2$. Another thing to check is if the point $Q$ is actually on the plane. Do its coordinates satisfy your plane equation? Some little error on the way might have given you the wrong point.